# Read multiples files in R allocated in different directories but with the same name

Tags: r

I am trying to solve a little problem in R about reading multiples files with the same name but allocated in different directories.

I have 100 files named `R04` and with extension `.xlsx`, but they are allocated in 100 different directories, like this:

`file 1:  C:\General Data\Month1\R04.xlsx`

`file 2:  C:\General Data\Month2\R04.xlsx`

`.`

`.`

`.`

`file 100: C:\General Data\Month2\R04.xlsx`

My problem is I can't get to read these files. Maybe it is possible to read they with `for`, and due to the same name in 100 files I don't know if is possible to name each one with a number related to the month, for example in the case of first file the name should be `01` due to month 1, etc.

Comment: Did you try reading a single file first?If yes, can you please post the code.

Comment: @Metrics @agstudy OK, When I read one file I make this, and all is fine: `setwd("D:/Documentos/Files/Month1")
library(RODBC)
Base="R04.xlsx"
conexion=odbcConnectExcel2007(Base)
Month1_R04=sqlQuery(channel=conexion,"select * from [Hoja1$]",as.is=TRUE)
close(conexion)` The problem is I have 100 different directories like `D:/Documentos/Files/Month1` with 2,3, etc. and I look for a way to make this with a loop with for because the number of months change and I will have 101, 102, etc. And you can see I will have another problem with the `Month1_R04` name structure for each file

Answer (score 1):

I would use `list.files` to list my files by pattern. Then some regular expression to name my files.

For example:

```
library(XLConnect)
files.path <- list.files(pattern=".*R04.xlsx",full.names=TRUE)
setNames(lapply(files.path, function(x) read.xlsx(x,1)),
         gsub('.*/(.*)/R04.*','\\1_R04',files.path))
```

Using some data to show how I am using `gsub`  here:

```
ll <- c("C:/General Data/Month1/R04.xlsx",
         "C:/General Data/Month2/R04.xlsx",
         "C:/General Data/Month3/R04.xlsx")
gsub('.*/(.*)/R04.*','\\1_R04',ll)
[1] "Month1_R04" "Month2_R04" "Month3_R04"
```

Comment: But I have the `R04` files in a diferents folders but not in the same!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the XLConnect package.

```
library(XLConnect)
file1 <- readWorksheet(loadWorkbook("C:\General Data\Month1\R04.xlsx"),sheet=1)
```